# group_replication.so not found in MYSQL 5.7.20

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, replication, library

At the time I enter on mysql shell:

**INSTALL PLUGIN group_replication SONAME 'group_replication.so';**

the shell returns:

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/group_replication.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/group_replication.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

and in fact inside there is no group_replication.so:

**ls /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/**

```
adtnull.so connectioncontrol.so keyringfile.so lockingservice.so mysqlnologin.so semisyncmaster.so validatepassword.so
authsocket.so innodbengine.so libmemcached.so mypluglib.so rewriter.so semisyncslave.so versiontoken.so
```

Currently I have mysql-server in 5.7.20 version.

On other forums only say that it must have the group_replication.so module, but where I have my server on digitalOcean, the repositories does not have it. Do I need to install it externally, an older version or what can I do?

Comment: I can confirm this! How did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I used other solution, but I answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a question on Digital Ocean and HuyCTNguyen answer:

I think you get error because You install mysql just with "apt-get install mysql-server" but before that. you must do step "Adding the MySQL Software Repository" ,follow this post for detail "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04"

I didn't test the answer because of time I used simple replication master to master.

But maybe this is useful for anyone and this answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little more context, it seems like the group replication isn't packaged with the standard enterprise MySQL server. It is instead available through the MySQL Community Version.

There is a little more detail on this issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535713/mysql-group-replication-plugin-not-found-in-version-5-7-19-5-7-21